# Clarification about Asymptotic comparison test for Improper integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

If I have an improper integral $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$,

and $b$ is the improper extrem, if $f(x)\sim g(x)$ for $x->b^-$, the integrals $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$have the same behaviour.

But is it true also if the improper extreme is $a$ and I have that $f(x)\sim g(x)$ for $x->a^+$?

My textbook doesn't say anything about it...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$
\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx=-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
$$ and, as $x \to b^-$,
$\displaystyle f(x)\sim g(x) 
$ is equivalent to 
$\displaystyle
-f(x)\sim -g(x)
$. Then only one extremity may be considered.

Comment: you're right! many thanks!