# For which $p$, $q$ does the improper integral exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> For which $p$, $q$ does the improper integral exist?
>   $$
> \text{(a)}\quad \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}
> \qquad\quad\text{(b)}\quad \int_0^\infty x^p |x-1|^q \, dx
> $$

I tried for (a) to simplify the problem

- if $p=q$ it doesn't exist

I am not sure if that's true. I am also having hard time solving (b).
I'd be thankful if you helped me with (b) at least.

Comment: Why do you think (a) doesn't exist when $p>q$? Because I doubt that.

Comment: If $q = 0$ and $p = 2$ then $p > q$ but the integral exists

Comment: You are right so I am having hard time at both a and b how can I solve such thing ?  A hint would help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [asymptotic comparison test for improper integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336600/clarification-about-asymptotic-comparison-test-for-improper-integrals) (no explicit integration is needed).

As regards (a), we have that, as $x\to 0^+$,
$$ \frac{1}{x^p+x^q}\sim\frac{1}{x^{\min(p,q)}}$$
and the integral is finite in $(0,a)$ iff $\min(p,q)<1$.

On the other hand as $x\to +\infty$,
$$ \frac{1}{x^p+x^q}\sim\frac{1}{x^{\max(p,q)}}$$
and the integral is finite in $(a,+\infty)$ iff $\max(p,q)>1$.

So we may conclude that the whole integral over $(0,+\infty)$ is convergent if and only if 
$$\min(p,q)<1\quad\text{AND}\quad \max(p,q)>1.$$

Now try (b) and note that in this case you should investigate what happens near $0^+$, $+\infty$ AND $1$.

i) if $x\to 0^+$ then
$$x^p |x-1|^q \sim x^p\implies ?$$

ii) if $x\to 1$ then
$$x^p |x-1|^q \sim |x-1|^q\implies ?$$

iii) if $x\to +\infty$ then
$$x^p |x-1|^q \sim x^{p+q}\implies ?$$

Comment: hello again thanks a lot for your help i have studied this test now i got that for $ (b) $ $\\$                                                          $ p+q > -1 $  and $ p>-1$ and $\\$ $q>-1$ can you check that for me please

Comment: @Mather $p>-1$ and $q>-1$ are correct. In case iii) since $x\to +\infty$ (there was a typo in my answer), the condition is $-(p+q)>1$ or $p+q<-1$.

Comment: the last condition i got that $p+q >-1 $ can you do show how please

Comment: i checked twice now , if we devide $x^p|x-1|^q$ by $|x-1|^{p+q}$ we get the asymptotic condition

Comment: and we know that $ \int |x-1|^{p+q} dx$ exist when $p+q > -1 $

Comment: oh boy never mind i got it we are in the condition x goes to $\infty $ omg

Comment: thanks a lot man you are a life savor !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is case (a). For it to converge, we have to have $\text{max}\{p,q\}>1$ and $\text{min}\{p,q\}<1$ Let $p-q=\alpha$.

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^p+x^q}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-q}}{1+x^{p-q}}\,dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{-q/\alpha}}{1+u} u^{1/\alpha-1}\,du \\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{(1-p)/\alpha}}{1+u}\,du \\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1-q}{\alpha}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{p-1}{\alpha}\big)}{\Gamma\big(1\big)} \tag{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-q}{\alpha}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{p-1}{\alpha}\right) \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{p-q}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-q}{p-q}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{p-1}{p-q}\right)
\end{align}
Where I've used an integral representation of the Beta function, and its relationship with the Gamma function in $(1)$.

Comment: is there any other easier way to solve because i am not familiar of beta/Gamma function ( its Real Numbers Calculas course )